# Get compiletime constants in C#

Tags: c#, msbuild, csc

In C# you can define compile-time constants that may be checked to configure compilation

```cs
#define MY_CONST
#if MY_CONST
    ...
#else
    ...
#endif
```

But I can't find a way to see which constants are defined at current line.
I need something like
`#warning DEFINED_CONSTANTS` that will give me `DEBUG; NET5_0`

Comment: might i ask for what purpose you want to do that? also: a complete list would be pretty long and quite illegible

Comment: usually you just check for a **specific** variable to be set. I can´t imagine why one would want to know all existing ones...

Comment: Yes, and after you get the list what you do with that list?

Comment: Since defines are precompiler directives, and may be set as compiler parameters, I'm not sure talking about "defined at current line" makes much sense. It might make sense at compile time for a compilation unit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After some time I've found that it is possible to show defined constants through MSBuild with

```xml
  <Target Name="ShowConstants" AfterTargets="AfterBuild">
    <Warning Text="$(DefineConstants)" />
  </Target>
```

which gives `TRACE;DEBUG;NET;NET5_0;NETCOREAPP` for net5.0 build.
It doesn't show constants for given line, but at least show constants for current configuration.

Comment: Thanks for you for coming back and posting the solution after the attitude you got here, I am really sorry for that and I really appreciate your help, and I've actually found it useful

Answer (score 1):

Disregarding everything else, you could just set a field

```
#if MY_CONST
   public static bool IsMyConst = true;
#else
   public static bool IsMyConst = false;
#endif
```

<sub>*Add pepper and salt to taste.*</sub>